# Add css class to noUiSlider handle on event

Tags: javascript, nouislider

By default on the [start event noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/) adds an active class to the active handle but removes it when the event has ended. I want a way to  show the user that the handle has been dragged already so changing the colour via a css class would be ideal.

I cannot tell which of the handles has been dragged from the data it provides.

Here is my function which initiates noUISlider

```
setRangeSlider(e) {
  const min = 0;
  const max = 1000000;
  noUiSlider.cssClasses.target += ' c-range-slider';
  const options = {
    start: [min || 0, max || this.maxAvailablePrice.id],
    step: 50000,
    tooltips: true,
    connect: true,
    range: {
      min,
      max,
    },
    format: {
      to(value) {
        return formatCurrency([value]);
      },
      from(value) {
        return stripFormatting(value);
      },
    },
  };
  this.slider = noUiSlider.create(e, options);

  this.slider.on('start', (values) => {
    console.log('SearchFiltersPriceComponent -> setRangeSlider -> this.slider', this.slider);
  });
}
```

When I console out `this.slider from the start event` it prints out all sorts of useful information but I cannot find which handle has just been dragged and how to target that handle to add a class to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.slider.target` will return the slider element and `handle` parameter in event callback function will return the index of the handle that has been dragged. so these two can be used together to locate a particular handle. see the code for example

```
setRangeSlider(e) {
  const min = 0;
  const max = 1000000;
  noUiSlider.cssClasses.target += ' c-range-slider';
  const options = {
    start: [min || 0, max || this.maxAvailablePrice.id],
    step: 50000,
    tooltips: true,
    connect: true,
    range: {
      min,
      max,
    },
    format: {
      to(value) {
        return formatCurrency([value]);
      },
      from(value) {
        return stripFormatting(value);
      },
    },
  };
  this.slider = noUiSlider.create(e, options);

  this.slider.on('start', (values, handle, unencoded, tap, positions, noUiSlider) => {
    let sliderElem = this.slider.target;
    let handleElem = document.querySelectorAll("div.noUi-handle[data-handle='" + handle + "']")[0];
    console.log('SearchFiltersPriceComponent -> setRangeSlider -> this.slider', handleElem);
     handleElem.classList.add("mystyle");
  });

  this.slider.on('end', (values, handle, unencoded, tap, positions, noUiSlider) => {
    let sliderElem = this.slider.target;
    let handleElem = document.querySelectorAll("div.noUi-handle[data-handle='"+handle+"']")[0];
    handleElem.classList.remove("mystyle");
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I wanted. Where did you find the documentation about passing in `handle` or those other options? I didn't see anything about that in the docs.

Comment: Actually just found it here, https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/ all under Binding. Thanks